# Zsh - split string by spaces when using dot operator

Tags: shell, scripting, split, zsh

Here is my script:

```
#/bin/bash
list="a b c"
for i in $list; do
  echo $i
done
```

This works:

```
➜  ~  ./lol.sh 
a
b
c
```

This doesn't:

```
➜  ~  . ./lol.sh 
a b c
```

Why split does not work with dot command and how can I fix it?

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem using bash 3 or bash 4.  What version are you running?

Comment: Oh darn. Just realized I use zsh.

Comment: ...so, the dot operator isn't actually a factor in this issue, except inasmuch as it changes which shell you're actually running the code in. Straighten out which shell in your environment is which, and you'll have removed it as a factor.

Comment: I too was having the same issue  - in zsh.... Using @CharlesDuffy info ... I modded my script. 

```bash

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lists should never be represented as strings. Use array syntax.

```
list=( a b c )
for i in "${list[@]}"; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

---

There are several reasons this is preferable.

## In ZSH:

- ZSH breaks POSIX by not performing string-splitting at all on unquoted expansions unless they explicitly request it. You can make this request by either running `setopt sh_word_split`, or using the parameter expansions `${=list}` or `${(ps: :)list}`

## In other Bourne-derived shells:

- String-splitting is dependent on the value of IFS, which cannot be guaranteed to be at defaults, *especially* when sourced from a separate script (which may have changed it locally).
- Unquoted expansion also performs globbing, which can have different results depending on which files are in the current working directory (for instance, if your list contains `hello[world]`, this will behave in an unexpected manner if your current directory contains files named `hellow`, `helloo`, or otherwise matching the glob).
- Avoiding the globbing step is not only more correct, but also more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, works in bash but zsh says: ./lol.sh: 2: ./lol.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Are you very, **very** sure you were testing with ZSH, not `/bin/sh`? `"(" unexpected` is exactly what you'd get from dash, ash or similar POSIX shells from that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87809/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-stipa).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I note the comment regarding lists by Charles Duffy, this was my solution/test.

```
#!/bin/zsh
function three()
{
        first=$1
        second=$2
        third=$3
        echo "1: $first 2: $second 3:$third"
}

setopt sh_word_split
set "1 A 2" "2 B 3" "3 C 4" "4 D 5"
for i;do
        three $i;

 done
```

This will output

```
1: 1 2: A 3:2
1: 2 2: B 3:3
1: 3 2: C 3:4
1: 4 2: D 3:5
```